# Given that $f:G\to G$ on a group $G$, defined by $f(x)=x^3$, is an isomorphism, how do I show that $G$ is abelian?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

Given that $f:G\to G$ on a group $G$, defined by $f(x)=x^3$, is an isomorphism, how do I show that $G$ is abelian, please?

Comment: Why did you change the question?

Comment: Headline should summarize the problem. Changing the original question to another one so also no good style.

Comment: I rolled back the question.  Absolute WWork, ask a new question if you want.

Answer (score 11):

Note that
$$
\forall a,b \in G: \quad ababab = (ab)^{3} = a^{3} b^{3} = aaabbb.
$$
Hence,
$$
\forall a,b \in G: \quad baba = aabb, \quad \text{or equivalently}, \quad (ba)^{2} = a^{2} b^{2}.
$$
Using this fact, we obtain
\begin{align}
\forall a,b \in G: \quad (ab)^{4} &= [(ab)^{2}]^{2} \\
                                  &= [b^{2} a^{2}]^{2} \\
                                  &= (a^{2})^{2} (b^{2})^{2} \\
                                  &= a^{4} b^{4} \\
                                  &= aaaabbbb.
\end{align}

- On the other hand,
  \begin{align}
  \forall a,b \in G: \quad (ab)^{4} &= abababab \\
                                    &= a (ba)^{3} b \\
                                    &= a b^{3} a^{3} b \\
                                    &= abbbaaab.
  \end{align}
- Hence, for all $ a,b \in G $, we have $ aaaabbbb = abbbaaab $, which yields
  $$
  f(ab) = a^{3} b^{3} = b^{3} a^{3} = f(ba).
  $$
  As $ f $ is injective, we conclude that $ ab = ba $ for all $ a,b \in G $.Hence $G$ is an **abelian** group

Comment: What do you think about this question? http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1434090/131887

Answer (score 1):

**Answer of the changed question:** Note that for any $a,b \in G$, $xy=f(x^{-1})f(y^{-1})=f(x^{-1}y^{-1})=f((yx)^{-1})=yx$.Hence $G$ is abelian.